# git merge origin/master and then resolve conflict leading to unrelated changes to submodule commits

Tags: git

I'm doing `git remote update` and then `git merge origin/master`. Aftering resolving conflicts and the push to remote dev branch, I can see some of the submodule commits are changed (i.e. the submodules aren't updated to the commits that's in the origin/master). Any idea how this can happen? Thank you!

Tried to use `git pull --rebase origin master` seems can resolve the issues of missing update to the submodule versions.

Comment: If  both your local repo and the remote repo changed the checked out commit of the submodule, I suppose it shows up as a merge conflict. Did you have to select this at conflict resolution?

Comment: The local repo doesn't change any of the submodules. However, when doing `git merge origin/master`, the conflicts would show that submodules have some updates, but not in the form of conflicts. I did add the submodules to staging. Maybe that's the reason for accidental submodule commit changes?